# How to display the time from now for date retrieved by MongoDB using momentjs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug, momentjs

I am using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to format the date to relative time retrieved from the mongodb passed to the view from the express router.

Here is my `.pug` file:

```
extends ../LoginLayout/LoginLayout
block content
    - var createdAt = requser.local.profile.createdAt
    script(type="text/javascript").
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var createdAt = createdAt;
            $('.memberSince')[0].innerHTML = moment().startOf(createdAt).fromNow(true);
        });

    .parallax-container.display
        .parallax
            img(src='http://lorempixel.com/1920/900')
        .container.white-text.center
            img.circle(src=requser.local.profile.dp style='width: 200px;')
            h1 #{requser.local.name}
            h6 Member Since #[span.memberSince #{createdAt}]
```

**This the screenshot of the output in the browser**:

[image]

---

**MORE INFO**

If I comment out this line from `.pug` file, this is the output (I guess pug automatically formats the date)
`// $('.memberSince')[0].innerHTML = moment().startOf(createdAt).fromNow(true);`

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

And the actual date stored in my MongoDB database is in the format:
[image]

Comment: how do you want show that date time ! relative or exact date time

Comment: @Robus I want to show in relative time, since I am using `.fromNow(true)` the param `true`, as mentioned in [doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) hides the work _ago_ from the text. I want to display this like: `Member since 4 days` or `Member since 5 months 7 days ` or `Member since 3 years 5 months` or `Member since 3hrs` depending upon the database.

Comment: @Robus I had updated the question info.

Comment: try .toNow(boolean) instead .fromNow(true)

Comment: this also could be used, `var start = moment.startof(CreatedAt)`  `var end = moment.now()`  `end.to(start)`

there are ample ways you can manipulate this. pls read to doc. time to X and time to now carefully

Comment: @Robus I tried both the method you suggested, but none seems to get the required output :(

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself.

Actually, what I did miss was I would have to pass **String** to the moment.

Here is the solved `.pug`:

```
- var createdAt = requser.local.profile.createdAt
script(type="text/javascript").
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var createdAt = Date.parse('!{createdAt}');            
        console.log(createdAt);
        $('.memberSince')[0].innerHTML = moment(createdAt).fromNow(true);
    })
```

I was also getting the output by simply using `var createdAt = '!{createdAt}'`, but in browser's developer console, it showed some depreciated warning of the passed string, so I parsed it to date using `Date.parse()`, and then passed the value as a *string* to `moment()`.

Also, you can see that there was no need of `.startOf()` and I am passing the `true` param to `fromNow()` as it simply removes the suffix *ago* from the output, as per docs.